# problem packages diagbox and cancel

Tags: cancel, diagbox

When using cancel package to cross out something and the package diagbox is also loaded the line does not appear in the proper location. When diagbox is not loaded everything works ok. However, I need to load that package to use it with some cells in tables.

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diagbox} 
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
Some text $\frac{ \cancel{2} \cdot \cancel{ \left( q_{1}+2 \right) } }{p_1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `diagbox` package internally loads `pict2e` which does some redefinitions that cause the problem with `cancel`; to prevent the redefinitions made by `pict2e`, load the `pict2e` package with the `original` option before `diagbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[original]{pict2e}
\usepackage{diagbox} 
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
Some text $\frac{ \cancel{2} \cdot \cancel{ \left( q_{1}+2 \right) } }{p_1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to pass the `original` option as class option, so `pict2e` will pick it up:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,original]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diagbox} 
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
Some text $\frac{ \cancel{2} \cdot \cancel{ \left( q_{1}+2 \right) } }{p_1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Dom You're welcome! ¡De nada!